# Running two commands using C and Linux environment variables

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm trying to run two commands using a C program and a Linux environment variable:

```
#Program name is execute
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  char cmd[256] = "/home/username/hello.sh $USER";
  execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-p", "-c", cmd, NULL); 

  return 0;
}
```

However, when running the program with the $USER environment variable set to a second command, the second command will not run.

```
env USER=";cat /home/username/hello.txt" ./execute
Hello from shell script
```

Hard coding the second command into the C program works:

```
char cmd[256] = "/home/username/hello.sh ;cat /home/username/hello.txt";

./execute
Hello from shell script
Hello from text file
```

I want my C program to return:

```
env USER=";cat /home/username/hello.txt" ./execute
Hello from shell script
Hello from text file
```

How can I get it to work, without changing the C program?

Answer (score 1):

The only processing that's done on the result of expanding variables is word splitting and globbing. It doesn't process characters like `;` to separate commands, `>` for output redirection, `$` for further variable expansions, etc.

If you want to force a full parse of the command, you have to use `eval`.

```
  char cmd[256] = "eval /home/username/hello.sh $USER";
  execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-p", "-c", cmd, (char*)NULL);
```